# How do I replace "Transfer Attribute" node in this case?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have blender 3.6.5 and am following a tutorial from blender 3.1.
In the [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Hn6G_iUW6lk?si=DUK2cMv1DvOjX3Bi&t=742) he uses a Transfer Attribute node but this node is replaced with other nodes is newer versions. I am still learning so I don't fully understand everything, like this subject.

I already tried to solve it in on my own by using a "Sample Nearest Surface" node, or a "Sample Nearest" & "Sample Index" node but I can't seem to solve the problem.
Anyone who can help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: it is the store named attribute/named attribute/sample index node.

Comment: Chong 3D uses "Sample Nearest Surface" node in the updated project. You can download a working .blend version from a link in his YouTube video description - (Download Link 2)